# How to overwrite lib template file - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, html, knockoutjs

How can the HTML files from the library be overwritten?

**I need to overwrite this template:**

- `lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html`

**I have tried placing the file in my own theme in the below locations**, I've cleared my cache between each file move.

- `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html`
- `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/gallery/gallery.html`
- `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/lib/mage/gallery/gallery.html`
- `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/lib/gallery/gallery.html`
- `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/mage/gallery/gallery.html`
- `app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/template/gallery/gallery.html`

I've read through the [dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/) and can't see anything mentioned in there either.

Comment: could you help me to find difference between `lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html` and `vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html`?

Comment: @LucaS I believe `/lib` and `/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib` are the same. If you check all the files there I think they will all be identical.

Comment: Yes, so why if they are identical they are both in magento project? What is their different purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it's the way Composer installs packages. Everything is installed to /vendor, so I'd take a guess that it copies the lib from the vendor magento2-base directory into the lib.

Comment: i think your answer is rational, i take it as mantra :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Correct Location

The correct location in this example is actually the first one I tried, I just didn't clear the directories required. So to overwrite lib templates they need duplicating in to the theme directory excluding the `lib` directory.

**Correct location -**`app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/web/mage/gallery/gallery.html`

### Clear pub/static and var/view_preprocessed

I actually placed the file in the correct location the first time, the main issue I had was that I wasn't clearing **pub/static** and **var/view_preprocessed** between file moves.

Comment: The correct location is already stated in the list of locations you tried in your question. Clearing the folders only fixed your problem or you typed the wrong locations ?

Comment: I believe my problem was I didn't clear pub/static and var/pre_processed. I thought clearing the cache was enough before I remembered the html templates are classed as static assets.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it a bit more obvious.

Comment: @BenCrook how can i override this file lib/web/mage/adminhtml/browser.js ?

Comment: @ND17 I haven't done anything with the adminhtml so this is a guess: `app/design/frontend/**vendor**/**theme**/web/mage/adminhtml/browser.js`